# Is there a closed form antiderivative for $ \int \frac{d y}{\sqrt{a e^{y}+y}} =\int \frac{d z}{z \sqrt{a z+\log z}} $?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have not been able to solve the following integral:

$$ \int \frac{d y}{\sqrt{a e^{y}+y}} =\int \frac{d z}{z \sqrt{a z+\log z}} $$

> We can take $a=0$ and it becomes elementary, but what about the general case? Can it be simplified?

---

The integral appears when trying to solve a second order nonlinear ODE:

$$
\frac{d^2 f}{dx^2}+\left(\frac{d f}{dx} \right)^2+f=0
$$

The ODE seems very interesting to me, so I would like to know if a closed form solution is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your friendly computer algebra system (e.g. Wolfram Alpha, if no other is available). If that one can't give you one, there most probably aren't.

Computer algebra systems use algorithms that are guaranteed to find antiderivatives if they can be written in terms of elementary functions (polynomials, powers, exponentials, logarithms, trigonometric functions and their inverses, and their compositions and ratios) and often if they can be written in terms of a largeish set of more exotic ones.

Comment: I checked with WA of course. Will check with Mathematica if I get the chance. It's not foolproof